# I added Subdivision Surface to my Model and It effect it The Bottom part of my Model

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I'm New to Modeling an I'm Trying to Make a Model and Using Subdivision Surface for the First Time But the Problem is the Model Looks Completely Fine But When I add Subdivision Surface to it everything's Fine except the Lower Region Any Fixes?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you show how you make subdivision and where

Comment: just show the area where you applied it...

Comment: make sure you don't have overlapping or inner faces or vertices

Comment: a picture in the edit mode would help